# COBOL plugin reports parse errors

Tags: cobol

Our team is running SonarQube instances for a variety of languages (java,pl/sql,C,C++).

Recently we were asked to run code quality analysis on COBOL code.

We have received some COBOL code from the development team and ran a Jenkins job.

During the analysis however we see some *parsing errors*.

Next to that no issues are found according to the analysis.

That is the very first time that we do not encounter any issues in an analysis so we are somewhat *suspicious* and wonder if the COBOL code is actually parsed in the correct way.

FYI we do not have any COBOL background ourselves.

I have pasted below some of the errors shown during the analysis.

In the end the analysis reports: *09:01:51.131 INFO  - 2/2 files analyzed*, but since we are not COBOL experts we wonder if the code is actually analyzed corretly?

**Details:**

- COBOL plugin: 1.17
- SonarQube: 3.7.3

**Questions we raised towards the development team:**

- The Cobol dialect (e.g : cobol-2002, microfocus, acucobol,tandem,gcos):
  *Tandem/NonStop    COBOL85 - T9257H01 - (15 MAR 09),      SCOBOLX   SCREEN COBOL - T0528H01* - (01FEB2009),   and ECOBOL (same as COBOL85, but different System Procedure Calls)
- What is the filename structure (e.g : myfile.cob): 
  *\system.$vol.subvol.filename   eg. \tdsdev.$dvs010.tdsrcdgs.gss2211*
- The Source format (e.g : fixed or free.  In fixed format, there is both a left and right margin. In free format, there is no margin and the indicator area is expected in column 1.):
  *free*
- If the format is fixed, what is the tab width?  Number of expanded spaces for a tab character (' '):
  *No, it is free format*
- Do you use copybooks , if so what are the file extentions ? (cpy,cbl ?):
  *Yes, we do use copybooks.  Tandem filenames are always having the same format :  \system.$vol.subvol.filename*

**Parse errors**
*Preprocessed contents:

```
Parse error at line 279:
  279:  01 MISCELLANEOUS-LITERALS .
       ^
  283:  05 L-ERROR-SIZE-ERROR PIC S9 ( 4 ) COMP VALUE 1 .
  284:  05 L-ERROR-CONTRACT-ORDER PIC S9 ( 4 ) COMP VALUE 2 .
  285:  05 L-ERROR-ORDER-SUBS-TRAFFIC PIC S9 (*
```

*Preprocessed contents:

```
Parse error at line 55:
   55:  01 LITERALS .
       ^
   56:  02 L-NO-CONTEXT-FOUND PIC 9 ( 4 ) COMP VALUE 5 .
   57:  02 L-ERROR-REQUEST-CODE PIC 9 ( 4 ) COMP VALUE 14 .
   58:  02 L-ERROR-READ-FIRST PIC 9 (
09:01:51.124 ERROR - Unable to parse COBOL source file : /home/ecbbuild/cobol/dvs010.tdsrcdgs.gsu2001l at line 279
Original contents starting from line 259 till line 299:
*                       48 : dependent end-pay
*
*                       When items is produced by ENDPAY request,
*                       50 is added to the values above
*
*    Encoding of internal-sort, when usage-plan discounts:
*
*       99PPPPPPPPQQQQQQFF
*       PPPPPPPP        Usage-plan-product-nr from line-total-adjust
*       QQQQQQ          First-start-date converted to georgian date,
*       FF              Usage-plan-display-aggregate-flag N=1, Y=2, D=3
*
*    Encoding of internal-sort, when information-item-type:
*
*       00PPPPPPPPYYYYMMDD
*       PPPPPPPP        product-reference-code OF inv-item-table
*       YYYYMMDD        item-from-date         OF inv-item-table
*
```

---

```
?SECTION gsu2001-error-literals
   01 miscellaneous-literals.
*
*     Reply-codes:
*
     05 l-error-size-error             pic S9(4) comp value  1.
     05 l-error-contract-order         pic S9(4) comp value  2.
     05 l-error-order-subs-traffic     pic S9(4) comp value  3.
     05 l-error-date-interval          pic S9(4) comp value  4.
     05 l-error-inv-item               pic S9(4) comp value  5.
     05 l-error-update-sold-product    pic S9(4) comp value  6.
     05 l-error-inv-item-text          pic S9(4) comp value  7.
     05 l-error-delete-sold-item-text  pic S9(4) comp value  9.
     05 l-error-sold-item-text         pic S9(4) comp value 14.
*-FAD-MOD-15.04.2005-#446902--------------------------------------------------*
*     05 l-error-line-total             pic S9(4) comp value 15.
*     05 l-error-line-total-adjust      pic S9(4) comp value 17.
     05 l-error-contract               pic S9(4) comp value 30.
     05 l-original-invoice-not-found   pic s9(4) comp value 38.
*     05 l-dup-error                    pic s9(4) comp value 39.
*     05 l-error-reading-cost-detail    pic s9(4) comp value 40.
***FIX IT - START*
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "COBOL".  There are specific dialects, as defined by particular compilers for particular machines.  How do you know, that the COBOL you are feeding to, uh, Jenkins(?) [There must be a specific tool you are running] is compatible with that tool? I raise this because you say you know nothing about COBOL.

Comment: Yout also don't clearly show a small COBOL program that doesn't parse, and the specific parse errors you get.  Why not?

Comment: Did you take any note of, and action related to, the responses from your COBOL team? Your analysis seems to be expected fixed-format, and they are using free-format. Also note that they are using three different "COBOL"s. Do you have access to the Tandem from your package? Unless your package is pretty magical, I suspect you'll have to pre-process the source for the copybooks, and watch for artifacts (like the ?SECTION). No, absolutely your package has pigs-breakfasted that program.

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess from my part: make sure you process the code as it is provided **including leading whitespace**. COBOL is not free-format (at leat not before COBOL 2002), so positions matter a lot - an asterisk marking a comment must be at column 7 etc.